# Given an undirected graph, how do you determine if there exists a path, that connects all nodes, so each node is only visited once?

Tags: graph-theory, theory

The graph can be cyclic or acyclic. The goal is to determine if a path *exists* from any node to another, where each node is visited once.

E.g. Graph

```
A <=> B
B <=> C
B <=> D
```

Would NOT have a path. There is no way to construct a path that contains every node, where each node is only visited once.

We can assume each edge has the same length, as we're only looking for the existence of a path. I couldn't find any good algorithms on this from an initial search, but I may have missed it!

This is just an interesting problem I came across. Let me know if more info is needed!

Comment: You can simplify your question by saying that you're looking for a way to check if a Hamiltonian path or circuit exists because a Hamiltonian path is a path that traverses every vertex and does not end on the vertex it started on and a Hamiltonian circuit is a path that traverses every vertex and ends on the vertex it started on. I believe this problem exists in NP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a [Hamiltonian path problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamiltonian_path) and there is no way to solve it easily. This problem belongs to NP-complete class and, in general, such problems require exponential amount of time and memory to be solved **exactly**. But there are some rather complex heuristical algorithms. As example, "traveling salesman problem" is a special case of Hamiltonian path problem, you can look at the ways to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

My solution was to loop through each vertex of the graph, and start there. Then recursively go through each neighboring node to see if a path was possible from that sub-path. But this solution is I believe n^2, so I was wondering if there was a better solution.

Pseudocode:

```
def check_graph(graph)
{
   foreach (vertex of graph)
   {
      if (is_path_possible(graph, vertex)
        return true;
   }

   return false;
}


def is_path_possible(graph, source) 
{
  if !graph.nodes.contains(source)
    return false;

  if graph.nodes.count == 1
    return true;

  foreach (neighbor of source)
  {
    child_graph = graph - source;

    is_child_path_possible = is_path_possible(child_graph, neighbor);

    if (is_child_path_possible)
      return true;
  }

  return false;
}
```